# Postgres summing up the difference between tables by time

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that gets a float reading every 5 minutes.

[image: Table]

I am trying to get the sum of difference between them
(reading now minus reading before that) in one hour format.

My attempts:

[image: Attempt]

But I don't want the sum of the `power` but the sum of difference.

Another attempt

```
select
date_trunc('hour', log_time) as per_hour,
sum(power-lag(power) over(order by log_time))
from log
where location_id='4'
and log_time BETWEEN now() - (interval '1 day') AND now()
group by per_hour, log_time, power
order by per_hour
```

The error I am getting:

```
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls
LINE 3: sum(power-lag(power) over(order by log_time))
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84505/how-to-calculate-the-cumulative-difference-between-rows-in-postgres take a look at this

Comment: sum of difference between what?.. power column? aggregated hourly power column?

Comment: @VaoTsun Sum of difference between power column.

Answer (score 0):

As you defined in comment:

> Sum of difference between power column

```
select sum(diff) from
(
select power - coalesce(lag(power) over (),power)  diff, * from log
) diff
```

I omitted `group by` and `order by` cos still don't understand the question.